# How do I find the line height of a UILabel?

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel

I have a button placed beneath a label and want to make it look like it's a continuation of a label. I think I can achieve this effect by changing the height of the button to match the UILabel's line height.

How do I get the line height of a UILabel?

Answer (score 4):

You can grab the height off of the **UIFont**:

```
label.font.lineHeight
```